# Which utility reads LSB headers in System V style init scripts?

Tags: init-script, init

Various older Linux distributions, which support *System V* type `init` scripts, require one to add LSB header to `init` script. For example a LSB header from `/etc/init.d/sshd` from OpenSUSE 11.4:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: sshd
# Required-Start: $network $remote_fs
# Required-Stop: $network $remote_fs
# Default-Start: 3 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 2 6
# Description: Start the sshd daemon
### END INIT INFO
```

However, `init` scripts should be simple bash scripts where every line, which begins with `#` is a comment. Which utility reads those LSB headers?

Comment: on debian it's `update-rc.d` which calls `insserv`. On Suse it is probably `chkconfig`.

Comment: Thanks! So in principal `chkconfig` calls the `insserv` utility which reads in init-scripts from `/etc/init.d/` and checks the data between `### BEGIN INIT INFO` and `### END INIT INFO`? Then `insserv` copies the init-scripts from `/etc/init.d/` to `/etc/rc.d/` and creates symlinks to `rc<runlevel>.d` directories according to information between the `### BEGIN INIT INFO` and `### END INIT INFO` lines?

Comment: I dont have a suse to check with, but that is what I understand happens. You can read about it here: [suse 11.4](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_114/opensuse-reference/cha.boot.html#sec.boot.init.skripte). This all changes in opensuse 12, which has adopted systemd.

Comment: @meuh Could you please mark your initial comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On debian it's `update-rc.d` which calls `insserv` (which is not usually run directly). On Suse it is probably `chkconfig`.
You can read about it here: [suse 11](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_114/opensuse-reference/cha.boot.html#sec.boot.init.skripte)

(note: this all changes in openSUSE 12, which has adopted `systemd`).